# Python Regex to match optionally double-quoted string

Tags: python, regex

I want to match an optionally double-quoted string with regular expression using Python regex module *re*

The expression should give the following results:

`"Assets".` => Should Match

`Assets.`   => Should Match

`"Assets.`  => Shouldn't Match

`Assets".`  => Shouldn't Match

I tried to achieve this using back reference in regular expression :

```
("?)Assets\1
```

However, it matches even if there is no matching end quote.
`"Assets.` -> neglects initial quote ", and matches the rest of the word.

What would be right expression for this ?

Comment: What if the string contains escaping (like `"Foo \" Bar"`?)

Comment: Whatever you're trying to parse with regex should probably not be parsed with regex.

Comment: Furthermore it is not really clear what should happen if there are quotes in the middle, like `Foo "" Bar`, etc. If you try to parse string *literals*, that is possible with a regex (although probably not advisable to do).

Comment: How do you identify the beginning and end of an unquoted value?

Answer (score 2):

You can use the following pattern. Note that it basically lists the two separate cases because parentheses are notoriously not regular, but context-sensitive and, thus, difficult to handle with regular expressions:

```
>>> p = re.compile(r'^(?:"[^"]+"|[^"]+)$')
>>> bool(p.match('"assets"'))
True
>>> bool(p.match('"assets'))
False
>>> bool(p.match('assets'))
True
```

This also assumes that are no chars before or after the string that is being matched.

Answer (score 1):

You regexp pattern is almost correct. You just have to make sure there are no quotes before and after your pattern. So use the pattern `r'(?<!")("?)Assets\1(?!")`

```
>>> words = ['"Assets"', 'Assets', '"Assets', 'Assets"']
>>> ptrn = re.compile(r'(?<!")("?)Assets\1(?!")')
>>> [bool(ptrn.match(word)) for word in words]
[True, True, False, False]
```